# Visual Studio не видит .NET framework при создании проекта C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, framework

Использую Visual Studio 2022:

При создании проекта Windows Forms App пишет, что не видит NET. framework, хотя в Installer выбирал загрузку Targetin' Pack

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал разные способы, но решения не нашел. Буду рад, если сможете помочь

Comment: скачайте да поставьте его отдельно

Comment: Вы можете создать Winforms на .NET 6, а не на древнем фреймворке, что мешает? Выберите другой шаблон, который без приписки "Framework". Но ситуация странная конечно.

Comment: Спасибо tym32167 и aepot за ответы, буду знать